# Should I post link as a comment or an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, comment-replies

Situation: [A question was asked.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4482921/find-limit-use-the-sandwich-theorem-using-inequality)

I tried to find a solution, but got stuck. [So I asked for help from MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4482990/follow-up-question-to-question-involving-lim-n-to-infty-frac-int-01-left) and am currently waiting for answers.

If I get a suitable answer, then I plan on posting [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4482990/follow-up-question-to-question-involving-lim-n-to-infty-frac-int-01-left) on to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4482921/find-limit-use-the-sandwich-theorem-using-inequality).

My question is: Should I post it as an answer (considering that this was a genuine effort to answer the question my part) or as a comment (considering that I’ll have nothing more to add besides the link)?

Comment: Do not post a link-only answer.  (1) Link only answers are generally deleted, and (2) those two questions appear to be exact duplicates---one of them really ought to be deleted.

Comment: @XanderHenderson the second question is posted by ME (the first is by someone else) regarding my attempt at the first question and how to proceed. They are not duplicates.

Comment: I am aware of the situation.  In my opinion, it was a Bad Idea™ to post your question.  It duplicates the earlier question without adding anything which significantly distinguishes it from that earlier question.

Comment: So what, in your opinion, should I do?

Comment: "Those two questions appear to be exact duplicates---one of them really ought to be deleted."  My opinion (moderator hat **off**) is that you should delete your question.  But others may have differing opinions.

Comment: @XanderHenderson sorry, I cannot delete my question anymore because it has received two very high-quality answers. Please don’t delete my question :)))) And yes, I’ll be posting my question as a comment to the original.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you want such a situation to never happen. It rids OP of their chance to  keep their question open by editing their question and improving it. Since if they were to actually do that then their question would be closed into your question.

However, I am in support of posting same question but requesting help for a specific approach if the question is very old (one or two week more age).

Comment: There was a possible solution to this suggested by a user named Sarvesh. If I understood them correctly, they say something similar to what you say/ edit the old question to of higher quality such that it stays on the site

Comment: An oddity of this pair of Questions is that the OP of the first main Math.SE Question has been around for some nine years, while insipidintegrator appears to be a very new (one month) user.  My point is that the longer term membership of these two does not suggest help should be needed from the new user in bringing the Question up to site standards.

Comment: In my opinion, in the time scale of this site, a question can be called *old* if it has been around for 2 years or so. I don't know where to draw the line for *very old* :-)